# retrieving IDs from PCA Rstudio

Tags: r, pca

I have a small issue regarding PCA Analysis in R.

I have used the package factoextra and the function PCA

I am trying to find the coordinates of the individual points related to the two main axis, but can't manage to obtain them. Indeed, the function PCA requires me to remove all IDs before running the PCA.

Would anybody know which function I could use ?

Comment: `factoextra::get_pca_ind()`

Comment: @Phil yes I can have the coordinates but how do I know the IDs linked to these results ? I had to drop them in order to run the PCA in the first place. Now instead of the names, I have some kind of index list from1 to 120 (121 companies) thanks in advance

Comment: They'll always be in the same order as what's in the original data frame

Comment: @Phil Perfect then ! Thanks a lot for the confirmation :) How do you know this however ? Is it somewhere in the description by any chance ?

Comment: It's just a common behaviour. I don't know of an instance in R where the output of a statistical function will change the order of data's rows unless you explicitly make it so.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this information. It is great !